# MySQLi Query Fails on Some Multiple Queries

Tags: php, sql

**EDIT: I just solved it by merging the INSERTS into a single query, but I'd still like to know why this was failing in the first place in case I encounter it again later.**

I'm currently using mysqli's query command to submit multiple queries, because I don't need to cycle through query results like multi_query allows. The main reason I didn't use multiquery was because I was having problems with using it more than once without closing and reopening the database. So if you have a solution for that problem, maybe it'll solve this one.

Because of my difficulties with multi_query, I finally just used query and put multiple queries inside of it, like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customers_attributes (ForeignCustomer, Type, Content, Date)
            VALUES ($customerID, 'PhoneNumber', '$phoneNumber', NOW());
            INSERT INTO customers_attributes (ForeignCustomer, Type, Content, Date)
            VALUES ($customerID, 'Email', '$email', NOW());
            INSERT INTO customers_attributes (ForeignCustomer, Type, Content, Date)
            VALUES ($customerID, 'CanEmail', '$emailMe', NOW());
            INSERT INTO customers_attributes (ForeignCustomer, Type, Content, Date)
            VALUES ($customerID, 'CanText', '$textMe', NOW());
        ";
    $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Now, the above code WORKS, however, when I attempt to do the exact same concept with this code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO jobs_notes (ForeignJob, ForeignUser, Type, Time, Content)
        VALUES ($jobID, 0, 'IssueDescription', NOW(), '$issueDescription');
        INSERT INTO jobs_notes (ForeignJob, ForeignUser, Type, Time, Content)
        VALUES ($jobID, 0, 'UserPassword', NOW(), '$userPassword');
        ";
if($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE)
    echo "Good";
else
    echo $mysqli->error;
```

It throws a generic error about the syntax of the third line of the SQL. I've had it print the query out with the variables, and run that directly in phpMyAdmin, and it runs fine, so the query is good, the problem seems to be with putting both queries together, even though it worked the first time. To test this, I tried out the code below, which works:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO jobs_notes (ForeignJob, ForeignUser, Type, Time, Content)
        VALUES ($jobID, 0, 'IssueDescription', NOW(), '$issueDescription');
        ";
echo "
$sql
";
if($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE)
    echo "Good";
else
    echo $mysqli->error;
$sql = "INSERT INTO jobs_notes (ForeignJob, ForeignUser, Type, Time, Content)
        VALUES ($jobID, 0, 'UserPassword', NOW(), '$userPassword');";

if($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE)
    echo "Good";
else
    echo $mysqli->error;
```

If you can either explain how to properly use multiple multiqueries for my purpose, or tell me why one is working and the other is not, either would be a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: What sort of error do you get?

Comment: You left out one of the most important pieces of information from your question... the error message. We can help you better if we know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: It was something along the lines of "error on line 3 near 'INSERT INTO jobs_notes (ForeignJob, ForeignUser, Type, Time, Content)'"

Answer (score -1):

Try **[mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)** instead of **mysqli_query** function.
It executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.

Comment: "The main reason I didn't use multiquery was because I was having problems with using it more than once without closing and reopening the database. So if you have a solution for that problem, maybe it'll solve this one."

Comment: Now, I definitely think you're right that multi_query should have been used here, but at this point I'd really just like to know why it worked once but not when I did the same thing a second time